# spring-boot returns 404 on html

Tags: spring-boot

I can't explain why my spring-boot app won't render my html pages anymore.  I am  running Spring-Boot 1.1.7 and have my index.html under src/main/resources/templates/.   I am using AutoConfiguration, but when I try to navigate to my home page, nothing is rendered and I get the following in my logs:

```
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Initializing servlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.a.c.c.C.[Tomcat].[localhost].[/]       : Initializing Spring FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization started
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Using MultipartResolver [org.springframework.web.multipart.support.StandardServletMultipartResolver@61c5f48e]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate LocaleResolver with name 'localeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.i18n.AcceptHeaderLocaleResolver@6e708e83]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate ThemeResolver with name 'themeResolver': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.theme.FixedThemeResolver@1bfeaf29]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate RequestToViewNameTranslator with name 'viewNameTranslator': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.view.DefaultRequestToViewNameTranslator@72f6365c]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Unable to locate FlashMapManager with name 'flashMapManager': using default [org.springframework.web.servlet.support.SessionFlashMapManager@38fb05a7]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Published WebApplicationContext of servlet 'dispatcherServlet' as ServletContext attribute with name [org.springframework.web.servlet.FrameworkServlet.CONTEXT.dispatcherServlet]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : FrameworkServlet 'dispatcherServlet': initialization completed in 24 ms
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Servlet 'dispatcherServlet' configured successfully
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Did not find handler method for [/]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Matching patterns for request [/] are [/**]
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : URI Template variables for request [/] are {}
o.s.w.s.handler.SimpleUrlHandlerMapping  : Mapping [/] to HandlerExecutionChain with handler [org.springframework.web.servlet.resource.ResourceHttpRequestHandler@54a232cd] and 1 interceptor
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/] is: -1
o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Ignoring invalid resource path []
o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : No matching resource found - returning 404
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Null ModelAndView returned to DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet': assuming HandlerAdapter completed request handling
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet' processing GET request for [/error]
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Looking up handler method for path /error
s.w.s.m.m.a.RequestMappingHandlerMapping : Returning handler method [public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.BasicErrorController.errorHtml(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)]
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Last-Modified value for [/error] is: -1
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Requested media types are [text/html, text/html;q=0.8] based on Accept header types and producible media types [text/html])
o.s.w.s.v.ContentNegotiatingViewResolver : Returning [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@54ca4ff0] based on requested media type 'text/html'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Rendering view [org.springframework.boot.autoconfigure.web.ErrorMvcAutoConfiguration$SpelView@54ca4ff0] in DispatcherServlet with name 'dispatcherServlet'
o.s.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet        : Successfully completed request
```

Here is my configuration:

```
@ComponentScan
@EnableAutoConfiguration
@EnableGlobalMethodSecurity(securedEnabled = true)
public class MyApplication {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ApplicationContext edm = SpringApplication.run( MyApplication.class, args );
    }
}
```

and I do have Spring-Security configured as:

```
@Configuration
@EnableWebMvcSecurity
public class WebSecurityConfig extends WebSecurityConfigurerAdapter {

    @Autowired
    private CustomUserDetailsService customUserDetailsService;

    @Override
    protected void configure(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception {
        http
                .authorizeRequests()
                .antMatchers("/").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/menu").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/error").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/resources/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/css/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/js/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/fonts/**").permitAll()
                .antMatchers("/libs/**").permitAll();
}
```

As I understand it, Spring-Boot MVC will give me the index.html, view resolvers, converters, etc. I was originally using a WebMvcConfigurerAdapter but I took that out as a part of trying to solve this. I don't think I really need it as I believe springmvc will just render each html that I link to provided its in the /template directory.  Except that it isn't finding them.

Comment: You are using Thymeleaf (otherwise `index.html` in `/templates` is not going to get rendered)?

Comment: ah, no I was not using Thymeleaf. I had removed Thymeleaf from my build, but have since put it back.  However, i still get 404 and see the "o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Ignoring invalid resource path []" in my logs.

Comment: It won't help you to have thymeleaf if you expect your index.html to be a welcome page. You need a `RequestMapping("/")` as well. If it's a static page, though, just put it in src/main/resources/static.

Comment: Thank you, moving my index.html now renders it.  I actually want all my pages to be static and the content will be filled in with json via AJAX calls. So it sounds like I need to have my pages under /static  and then have a @Controller for each page with a GET to return the page name?  I notice if I take the Thymeleaf out of my build, then I get circular references because spring-mvc doesn't know how to handle the page.

Comment: You don't need a `@Controller` to serve static content, unless you need the resource path to be different than the file path under /static (just put it in /static). So you definitely don't need thymeleaf.

Comment: If I move all my html files under "/src/main/resources/static" then the only page that actually renders is the index.html.  Every other page requested returns a 404.  There is even a log message that **o.s.w.s.r.ResourceHttpRequestHandler     : Trying relative path [ about ] against base location: class path resource [static/]**  But I must have something messed up.

Comment: The index.html is special because it is a welcome page (so it renders on "/"). The others all will need a full path including the .html extension. The static folder is not resolvable as static/ - its contents show up under /.

Comment: i have a problem similar to this. Can someone help me a check my question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32957553/spring-boot-request-endpoints-return-404. Thanks for help