# spring boot request endpoints return 404

Tags: java, spring, maven, spring-mvc, spring-boot

i build a new java project with spring-boot and maven, but i cannot access my endpoints.

This a part of a console when i start tomcat, i can see all the all endpoints:

```
DEBUG [localhost-startStop-1] security.OAuth2ServerConfiguration: AuthorizationServerConfigurationorg.springframework.security.oauth2.config.annotation.web.configurers.AuthorizationServerEndpointsConfigurer@f8f122
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/metrics/{name:.*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.MetricsMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/metrics],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/beans],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/mappings],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/autoconfig],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/info],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/dump],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/health]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.HealthMvcEndpoint.invoke(java.security.Principal)
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/trace],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/configprops],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/env/{name:.*}],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EnvironmentMvcEndpoint.value(java.lang.String)
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] mvc.EndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/env],methods=[GET]}" onto public java.lang.Object org.springframework.boot.actuate.endpoint.mvc.EndpointMvcAdapter.invoke()
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize],methods=[POST],params=[user_oauth_approval]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.View org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.approveOrDeny(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/authorize]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.AuthorizationEndpoint.authorize(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>,org.springframework.web.bind.support.SessionStatus,java.security.Principal)
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[GET]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.getAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/token],methods=[POST]}" onto public org.springframework.http.ResponseEntity<org.springframework.security.oauth2.common.OAuth2AccessToken> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.TokenEndpoint.postAccessToken(java.security.Principal,java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.String>) throws org.springframework.web.HttpRequestMethodNotSupportedException
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/check_token]}" onto public java.util.Map<java.lang.String, ?> org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.CheckTokenEndpoint.checkToken(java.lang.String)
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/confirm_access]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelApprovalEndpoint.getAccessConfirmation(java.util.Map<java.lang.String, java.lang.Object>,javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest) throws java.lang.Exception
INFO  [localhost-startStop-1] endpoint.FrameworkEndpointHandlerMapping: Mapped "{[/oauth/error]}" onto public org.springframework.web.servlet.ModelAndView org.springframework.security.oauth2.provider.endpoint.WhitelabelErrorEndpoint.handleError(javax.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest)
```

when i send q request for example:

```
curl -v http://localhost:8080/env
```

i get an http error with 404

```
 Hostname was NOT found in DNS cache
*   Trying 127.0.0.1...
* Connected to localhost (127.0.0.1) port 8080 (#0)
> GET /env HTTP/1.1
> User-Agent: curl/7.35.0
> Host: localhost:8080
> Accept: */*
> 
< HTTP/1.1 404 Not Found
* Server Apache-Coyote/1.1 is not blacklisted
< Server: Apache-Coyote/1.1
< Content-Type: text/html;charset=utf-8
< Content-Language: en
< Content-Length: 1006
< Date: Mon, 05 Oct 2015 20:27:45 GMT
< 
* Connection #0 to host localhost left intact
<!DOCTYPE html><html><head><title>Apache Tomcat/8.0.20 - Error
```

how should i access my endpoints? I have the same problems for all the endpoints: oauth/token, health, metrics, ....

If someone want to see all the project, please check this question:
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812830/spring-boot-oauth2-authentification-error

Thanks for help

Comment: Have you tried accessing http://localhost:8080/env through browser?

Comment: Could you please provide your main Spring Boot Application source code?

Comment: Check this question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/32812830/spring-boot-oauth2-authentification-error

Comment: @CrazySabbath  the browser return me the same: 404

Comment: @emoleumassi, Can you restart your spring web application and post full log here?